# How to lock OS X after autologin with a script

Tags: macos, script, applescript, auto-login

I want to lock my Mac running OS X 10.8 after it has powered up with a script.

I have autologin enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the AppleScript Editor, and type in this command:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend`

Save it as a script file. Then, open your System Preferences, go to Account, and add it to the programs that will run upon login.

This command will not log you out; it does the same thing as using the fast user switcher.

Comment: I don't know of a better solution than Stephen's (I use it myself) but it's worth noting this isn't 100% secure. Login items can be disabled by pressing a key combination as the login process begins. I'm omitting the specific combination but anyone can figure it out.

Comment: @FormerMacGenius Good to know. I hadn't thought of that. Depending on the Questioner's situation it may or may not be sufficient for their purpose.

Comment: See my answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361764/254034. You can make it a launchctl script that runs even with the shift key pressed on login, that prevents all apps saved as startup items from starting.

Comment: This works great! Just had to use `do shell script` to run the command: `do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend"`